# How to install npm package from python script?

Tags: python, node.js, sublimetext2, npm

How to install npm package from a python script?

**When I use** `subprocess.Popen(["node", "app.js"])` it is **OK**.
**When I use** `subprocess.Popen(["npm", "install", "open"])` it is **throwing an error**.

*Sorry, but Google and DuckDuckGo are not my friends today(*

**The main problem** — automatic local installation required packages for my small utility because global packages are not working in windows.

**PS.** I have to ask this question because I’m trying to develop a plugin for Sublime Text 2.

This is the **error in Sublime python console**:

```
Reloading plugin …\stsync.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\sublime_plugin.py", line 103, in create_application_commands
    cmds.append(class_())
  File ".\stsync.py", line 16, in __init__
  File ".\subprocess.py", line 633, in __init__
  File ".\subprocess.py", line 842, in _execute_child
WindowsError: [Error 2]
```

line 16: `subprocess.Popen(["node", "npm", "install", "open"])`

---

**If I change** line 16 to **subprocess.Popen(["node", "npm", "install", "open"])**
then the python script will successfully invoke the nodejs terminal, but then it will fail with error:
`cannot find npm module`
[image: nodejs error]

Comment: What error? Does typing npm into a command window work?

Comment: @wdavo in terminal node and npm are working ok

Comment: @wdavo I added some context in question

Comment: I once created this helper https://github.com/miohtama/vvv/blob/master/vvv/sysdeps.py#L221 if it's any useful for you

Answer (score 5):

set the `shell` argument to True

```
subprocess.Popen(["node", "npm", "install", "open"], shell=True)
```

Comment: Is there any other option besides using shell=True? As per the documentation https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments, using shell=True is a security hazard and and its use is strongly discouraged.

Comment: Hi there, this one doesn't seem to be working for me? It gave me some weird error

Answer (score 2):

On Windows, many of the Node.js "binaries" are actually suffixed with the `.cmd` filename extension, which for whatever reason during the invocation through `subprocess.Popen`, it doesn't expand (even though `PATHEXT` might contain `.cmd`).

So for a proper solution (that does not use `shell=True`), try append `.cmd` to the Node.js binaries needed:

```
Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 25 2016, 22:01:18) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (In
tel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.Popen(['npm.cmd', 'install'])
<subprocess.Popen object at 0x005E18B0>
>>> npm ERR! install Couldn't read dependencies
```

Of course it throws an error because I don't have a `package.json` in that directory.  Try again using some other commonly used programs, such as `webpack`:

```
>>> subprocess.Popen(['webpack'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
...
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Oh right, add that `.cmd`:

```
>>> subprocess.Popen(['webpack.cmd'])
<subprocess.Popen object at 0x008A18B0>
>>> No configuration file found and no output filename configured via CLI option
```