# Run npm commands using Python subprocess

Tags: python, node.js, npm, yuidoc

I'm trying to automate the generation of documentation using YUIDOC, but I have a server side framework that heavily uses python, so I'm trying to automate everything from within a python script.  I'm able to get the node command to run fine, but whenever I try something I installed using npm, python isn't happy.  My project uses Buildout instead of virtualenv, but ideally I'd like to be able to just run these commands from a standalone python file.

Perhaps some code would help explain my situation:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_call('node --help')

#SUCCESS

import subprocess
subprocess.check_call('npm --help')

#FAIL
#WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified

import subprocess
subprocess.check_call('yuidoc --help')

#FAIL
#WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I already tried adding the folder where the yuidoc and npm stuff lives to the sys.path of python, but that didn't work.

ps, this is sort of a similar question to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14680733/how-to-install-npm-package-from-python-script).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I needed to specify `shell=True` in the check_call.

```
subprocess.check_call('npm --help', shell=True)

subprocess.check_call('yuidoc --help', shell=True)
```

Comment: [Invoking by shell is not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3172488/3936044). I suggest `check_call('npm.cmd --help')`, it's from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50045443/3936044) in the related thread you mentioned