# subprocess.run failure vs subprocess.check_call success

Tags: python, node.js, subprocess

I have a problem launching a npm command via a python script.

from [Run npm commands using Python subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28891053/run-npm-commands-using-python-subprocess) I found that the following should work:

```
subprocess.check_call('start npm run features:chrome:server', shell=True)
```

and it does (!).

From documentation (https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html), I read that `subprocess.check_call` is equivalent to `run(..., check=True)`

As I previousely used subprocess.run to launch an external application (newman) with success, I tried the following:

```
subprocess.run("start npm run features:chrome:server", check=True)
```

but it ends up with an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_differentiel.py", line 73, in <module>
    subprocess.run("start npm run features:chrome:server")
  File "C:\Users\a.joly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 403, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "C:\Users\a.joly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 707, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\a.joly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 990, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Le fichier spécifié est introuvable
```

Any idea of why I can't use subprocess.run ? (nor check_output, by the way ...)

Comment: From the error message, you forget to add `shell=True` in `subprocess.run()`, hence the full string `'start npm run features:chrome:server'` is assumed to be the target executable. And I think it's safe to assume that that file doesn't exist ...

Comment: good point, I didn't set shell=True, let's try it ...  ! great ! it works !  :) thank you.

Comment: `shell=True` splits the argument string (by passing it to the shell). `shell=False` tries to a run an executable named `'start npm run features:chrome:server'` (the full string with spaces, not just `start.exe`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct execution is
`subprocess.run(['start', 'npm', 'run', 'features:chrome:server'], check=True)`

`subprocess.check_call('start npm run features:chrome:server', shell=True)` works because you invoked the shell. Further information you could find [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#security-considerations).

`subprocess.run("start npm run features:chrome:server", check=True, shell=True)` should also work.

Comment: This doesn't work actually, shell=True is really the point ... though the syntax may be more pythonic (?)